# Is this an idiomatic C way to convert longs to a binary (char *) representation?

Tags: c, binary, type-conversion

The question is in the title I guess.

This is the temporary solution I came up with but I was wondering:

- If there are disadvantages to representing binary as char*. Is there a better way (considering i would want the ability of bit-shifting etc...)
- If there is obvious non-idiomatic C (or other errors) in the code below.

All suggestions welcome...

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* compile with 
    gcc -lm -std=c99 
*/

void binary_repr(unsigned long input) {
    int needed_digits = (int) (floor(log2(input)) + 1);
    char *ptr_binarray = malloc((needed_digits + 1) * sizeof (char));
    int idx = (needed_digits);

    if (ptr_binarray == NULL) {
            printf("Unable to allocate memory.");
        exit(1);
    } 
    else {
        do {
            idx--;
            if (input % 2 == 0) { 
                ptr_binarray[idx] = '0'; 
            } 
            else { 
                ptr_binarray[idx] = '1'; 
            }
            input = input / 2;

        } while (input > 0);

        ptr_binarray[needed_digits] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", ptr_binarray);
        free(ptr_binarray);
        ptr_binarray = NULL;
    }
}

int main()
{
    binary_repr(8);
    binary_repr(14);
    binary_repr(4097);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `x * sizeof(char)` can just be `x` since `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition.

Comment: I wouldn't call "idiomatic" something that big :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks approximately idiomatic to me, except that I'd write the loop something like:

```
char *writeptr = ptr_binarray + needed_digits;
*writeptr = 0;
do {
    --writeptr;
    *writeptr = (input % 2) + '0';
    input /= 2;
} while (input > 0);
```

No need for an integer index.

For this particular case, I wouldn't bother with `malloc` since you `free` in the same function. Just allocate a big enough char array on the stack:

```
char binarray[sizeof(unsigned long)*CHAR_BIT + 1];
```

Or make use of C99's variable length arrays:

```
char binarray[needed_digits + 1];
```

Also, if you're only using gcc, then rather than taking a logarithm you could consider using `__builtin_clz` to calculate `needed_digits`. That's not about idiomatic C, though, since it's the gcc dialect. But even without it, you don't need floating point math to figure out how many digits are needed:

http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLogObvious

Just noticed a probable error in that line, too - your do/while loop neatly handles the case where `input` is 0, but the first line doesn't since you can't take the log of 0.

*Is there a better way (considering i would want the ability of bit-shifting etc...)*

Not sure what you mean here. If you want to do operations like bit-shifting on a value, then don't convert it to a string like this. Keep it as a `long int`, and do your bit-shifting there.

Other minor things, since you're asking for general opinions. None of these are things I'd really criticise as long as you have a reason you've done them:

- Remove pointless parens around (`needed_digits`), it's just noise.
- Error message should probably go to stderr rather than stdout.
- I would always check the return value from malloc (or any other function that returns an error value) immediately, rather than have a line of code in between. So move the `int idx = needed_digits` line down to just before the 'do .. while' loop (since you're using std=c99. If it was c89, then you could still do that except that I'm going to recommend...).
- I wouldn't put an "else" after a conditional exit or return. But other people would do as you have, and the argument can probably get tribal.
- Personally I wouldn't multiply by `sizeof(char)` in malloc, since the size of the buffer allocated by malloc is measured in chars by definition. But others put it there so that every malloc consistently always has a sizeof, so again I can't claim my way is idiomatic. It's just better ;-)
- Clearing pointers after free is arguably worthwhile when they're in a structure, but not so much for automatics.

For each of the last three things, good C programming practice would not necessarily be to do as I do, but to agree a coding style with your colleagues / collaborators. The coding standard is allowed to be "do as you prefer", just so long as you agree not to argue, and not to "tidy up" each other's code.

Comment: +1 - good depth, and the code example is clean and elegant as well.

Comment: Perfect! These are exactly the kind of answers I was looking for. I'll try to update the code in question if I find any spare time tomorrow evening.

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to “convert” numbers to binary representation; they are already represented in binary inside memory.
Using bitwise operators it's quite easy to play with binary representation:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

static void binary_repr(unsigned long input);

int main (void)
{
    binary_repr(0);
    binary_repr(1);
    binary_repr(16);

    return 0;
}

static void binary_repr(unsigned long input)
{
    unsigned int i;
    unsigned int nb_bits = sizeof(input) * CHAR_BIT;

    for (i = 0; i < nb_bits; ++i)
    {
        /* print the left-most bit */
        putchar((input & (1 << (nb_bits - 1))) == 0 ? '0' : '1');
        /* left-shift by onex */
        input <<= 1;
    }

    putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: Very nice, concise way. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

You could use glibc to register a custom printf conversion specifier:

[Customizing printf](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Customizing-Printf.html)

Then you could do:

```
printf("Binary Representation:  %b\n", num);
```

This would be more flexible than having a call to printf() inside your function.

You would still need to specify a function to do the conversion; but then you could use (s)printf throughout the code.

Bastien Léonard's answer has a more idiomatic function to do the conversion, using bitwise-and instead of modulo 2, bit-shifting instead of division, and the ternary operator instead of if else.

Here is a related question:

[is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111928/is-there-a-printf-converter-to-print-in-binary-format)

Answer (score 3):

```
itoa(value, output_buffer, base);
```

If you use 2 for base, you'll get the binary version in the string.

Note that I'm only answering "*Is there a better way*", not any other component of the question.

EDIT: Also, you may want to look at popular implementations of itoa to see how they did the multi-base conversion without requiring math functions (from -lm). I know a lot of itoa's I've seen are quite small and elegant and still quite powerful.

Comment: Funny, I've never seen itoa(). What standard is that in?

Comment: I don't think that itoa() is standard.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itoa, "The itoa function is a widespread non-standard extension to the standard C programming language".

Comment: Alternatively you can also look at ltostr, however that's not really standardised either.

Comment: I don't have an `itoa()` on OS X, so you're going to have to roll your own for portability anyway, unless you don't care about us OS X users. \*tear\*

Comment: There's an itoa() implementation in K&R, so it should be right next to you :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you converting to (char *) because you want the ability to bit shift?  If so, are you aware of the bit shift operator?

```
short int n = 1;  //0x0001
n = n << 1;       //shift bits 1 place to the left
                  //n is now 2; 0x0010
```

Just for giggles, here's a routine for printing the binary representation using the bit shift operator:

```
void printbitssimple(int n) {
    unsigned int i;
    i = 1<<(sizeof(n) * 8 - 1);

    while (i > 0) {
        if (n & i)
            printf("1");
        else
            printf("0");
        i >>= 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well basically I want to convert longs to char * for playing with binary multiplication (where the product is bigger than the long datatype limits). I should probably have included this information in my question. Thanks for taking the time to answer (and the insight)!

Answer (score 2):

Ok, another possible solution using look-up table:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#undef BIGENDIAN

#ifdef BIGENDIAN
enum { TSIZE = sizeof(int), INIT = 0, END = TSIZE };
#define op(x) ++(x)
#define cond(x) ((x) < END)

#else
enum { TSIZE = sizeof(int), INIT = TSIZE - 1, END = -1 };
#define op(x) --(x)
#define cond(x) ((x) > END)

#endif

static char *binstr[] = {
  "0000", // 0x0
  "0001", // 0x1
  "0010", // 0x2
  "0011", // 0x3
  "0100", // 0x4
  "0101", // 0x5
  "0110", // 0x6
  "0111", // 0x7
  "1000", // 0x8
  "1001", // 0x9
  "1010", // 0xA
  "1011", // 0xB
  "1100", // 0xC
  "1101", // 0xD
  "1110", // 0xE
  "1111", // 0xF
};


int main(void)
{
  int num, i;
  unsigned char *hex;

  hex = ((unsigned char *) &num);
  while(fscanf(stdin, "%i", &num) != EOF)
  {
    for(i = INIT; cond(i); op(i))
      printf("%s%s", binstr[hex[i]>>4], binstr[hex[i]&0xF]);
    printf("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

PD: I only check with little-endian memory organization.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option. This simply loops over all bits from the most significant to the least significant and checks if they are set.

```
void binary_repr(unsigned long input)
{
    int i = sizeof(input) * 8 - 1;
    for (; i >= 0; --i) {
        putchar((input & (1 << i)) == 0 ? '0' : '1');
    }

    putchar('\n');
}
```

This doesn't do anything that hasn't already been suggested by other people here. It's just a method that's easier to remember for me.

Answer (score 1):

It's one of the great tragedies of Arabic notation that we put the most significant digit first.  Almost all computations are easier when we start with the least significant digit:

```
void fprint_binary(FILE *fp, unsigned long n) {
  char digits[8*sizeof(n)+1];
  char *p = digits+sizeof(digits)-1;
  *p = '\0';
  unsigned long mask;
  for (mask = 1; mask; mask <<= 1)
    *--p = mask & n ? '1' : '0';
  while (*p == '0')
    p++;
  fprintf(fp, "%s", *p ? p : "0");
}
```

The comments about representation go double if you ever write code for a Turing machine (exercise for students, not practical).